# Getting selenium java to click in the middle of the browser window

Tags: selenium

Getting selenium java to click in the middle of the browser window.

I just need it to click in the middle of the window (so I can pause an embedded video).

Comment: Why can't you just use findElement to find it and perform normal click() on it?

Comment: It has no id, and im having difficulty finding the frame atm

Answer (score 1):

To click in the middle of the browser window:

```
Dimension window = driver.manage().window().getSize();
new Actions(driver)
        .moveByOffset(window.getHeight() / 2, window.getWidth() / 2)
        .click()
        .build()
        .perform();
```

but better provide locator of video to click directly on it, and not on abstract "middle of the browser window"

Comment: So i tried it but i guess it might not work with an embeded video. Any ideas?